# scraping prices using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to scrap the images of the products from some sites, I am using javascript to scrape it.
so far i have been successfully scraping the images, like below

```
var  images = document.images;

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    img =  images[i];
```

i also want to scrape the prices from the document. i know this is possible and some sites are already doing this but not sure how.
something like matching the "Price" string through the document text seems to be a possibility but not sure how to do that and also is there any better way.
any pointers?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean "scrape" rather than "scrap".

Comment: What do you mean by scrapping? :S

Comment: @mattytommo he means he's grabbing the web page, in php we use file_get_contents(), and traversing the returned obj/string.. whatever.

Comment: lol sorry was quick on the enter key.

Comment: @MattMoore Ah okay cool, thanks for clearing that up

Comment: @asm234 have you looked over the containers for the prices? Usually they have a class for styling. You can pull the content out of all these classes and have a list of prices. Honestly, its hard to help without a print out of the page you're scrapping.

Comment: Assuming the prices are close in the document tree you could just poke around from there... `images[i].nextSibling` ??

Comment: @rlemon yes it seems to be a possibility i did not know about this, i will try, definitely  a point of help thanks.

Comment: @Matt Moore there is no single set of pages, there are many. so i cant rely on one particular

Comment: @asm234 If you are pulling from multiple pages you're going to have to use multiple scrappers.

Comment: @asm234 if you could provide an example of the HTML you're parsing for this information I might be of some more help.

Comment: @rlemon take any page from any store which has product and its price .. pick any page.

Comment: ok. I see what you mean so you want a generic failsafe way to do this? I don't think that is feasible without knowing the markdown your parsing... you'll have to have some kinda idea where the corresponding values are.

Comment: yes somekind of idea has to be made and that is usally finding out the class name matching price

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much you know about the page in question. If you're going in blind, you could always use something as horrible as `document.body.innerHTML.match(/£\d+\.\d+/g)` (or something similar, depending on currency). Either way, you will want to find and match patterns in the page and grab the prices from there.

For bonus points: See if they have a google base feed (unprotected) - you'd be surprised how many people do. This will (usually) be an XML feed with everything you could possible need.

Comment: I will have to look into this 'google base feed' you speak of.

Comment: @leonard, your answer seems to be interesting.
can you please explain me the meaning of regex you defined here, am sorry am kind of beginner in regex n js.
i will look into the google feed more. not sure what exactly it is.

Comment: A great introduction to regex (regular expressions): www.regular-expressions.info/

Google Base is another name for Google Shopping/Products - it's where merchants tell Google what products they have on offer so Google can show them through their shopping web site. They provide this information via a feed, usually xml (sometimes CSV). Sometimes it's possible to figure out/guess/ask for access to these feeds, which will make your life a lot easier.